# jar created with ant is invalid

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javac

I have two projects in my Eclipse:

1. simple java project
2. Dynamic Web Project, that is dependent on the above project

Everything works fine, when I run the 2nd project from Eclipse. But I use `ivy` for dependency management and `ant` as a build system.
I build project 1 and publish it to Nexus. Everything seems to work properly: jar and pom are created and published. But, when I use the publish jar for creating a war from the 2nd project I get `ClassCastException` error, when trying to run the web application. If I replace `filtertableconfigurator.jar` with the one generated "in hand" (Export --> Java --> JAR file) in Tomcat, application starts to work properly. So the problem is with ant or ivy.
 Any ideas about reasons? And, primary, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is really with the compiler :-(. Adding:

```
<property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
```

to `build.xml` and `ejc.jar` to ant classpath resolves the problem. But I don't like the solution and don't understand a clue of the problem :-(